# Generation of all possible permutations using backtracking

Tags: python, recursion, permutation, backtracking

I am new to programming and I was going through some basic backtracking problems. One of these was to print all possible permutations of a list. I got the following code from the internet.

```
def permutation(arr,size,n):
    if size == 1:
        print(arr)
        return
    for i in range(size):
        permutation(arr,size-1,n)
        if size & 1:
            arr[0],arr[size-1] = arr[size-1],arr[0]
        else:
            arr[i],arr[size-1] = arr[size-1],arr[i]
```

This is working fine and it printed the following output for input arr = [1,2,3]

```
[1,2,3] [2,1,3] [3,1,2] [1,3,2] [2,3,1] [3,2,1]
```

Now I want to store all these possible permutations into a different array and for that modified the code into this.

```
 ans = []
 def permutation(arr,size,n):
    if size == 1:
        ans.append(arr)
    for i in range(size):
        permutation(arr,size-1,n)
        if size & 1:
            arr[0],arr[size-1] = arr[size-1],arr[0]
        else:
            arr[i],arr[size-1] = arr[size-1],arr[i]
```

But when I printed the list and, it printed this.

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I store all the possible permutations into a list?

Comment: After `if size == 1:` you have `return` in the first code, but **not** in the second code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: People still upvoting duplicates of the most duplicated Python question. Weird.

Comment: @superbrain the problem here is using two seemingly same code, that are actually not the same. In this sense, it is not duplicate

Comment: @JanStránský The only non-duplicate here is the same list object stuffed into the result list over and over again. Same problem as in that other question.

Comment: @superbrain I see two question. "How can I store all the possible permutations into a list?" this is for sure duplicate. But "What am I doing wrong here?" deserves an answer

Comment: change `ans.append(arr)` to `ans.append(arr[:])` and `return` afterwards.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Interestingly, the `return` doesn't appear to be needed.

Comment: @superb rain Yes, I missed that when I ran the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you always append a reference to the same instance of the `arr` object (which is a list) to the `ans` list. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) for a similar situation.

You don't have this problem in the first code, because you simply print the list at each permutation. But in the second code you manipulate *the same* list at every recursion, and when you are at top of you recursion tree you get back the original list (`[1, 2, 3]`).

To solve the problem, you can add a *deep copy* of you your list to the `ans`:

```py
def permutation(arr, size, n):
    if size == 1:
        # ans.append(arr)

        # this copies every element of arr into a 
        # new list and then appends the new list to ans.
        ans.append([e for e in arr]) 

    for i in range(size):
        permutation(arr, size-1, n)
        if size & 1:
            arr[0], arr[size-1] = arr[size-1], arr[0]
        else:
            arr[i], arr[size-1] = arr[size-1], arr[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer**, not answering the question (see edit)

Answering the "What am I doing wrong here?" question.

You have

```py
    if size == 1:
        print(arr)
        return
```

in the first code, but

```py
    if size == 1:
        ans.append(arr)
```

Try:

```py
    if size == 1:
        ans.append(arr)
        return
```

and it should work as expected

**EDIT**:

thanks to @superbrain for criticism, it really did not work, I was too optimistic about code correctness in the OP.

So the answer for "What am I doing wrong here?" is this line

```py
        ans.append(arr)
```

where you append **the same instance of list** every time, so you end with list of the same objects

It is similar to this scenario:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = []
list2.append(list1)
list2.append(list1)
print(list2) # [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
list1[2] = 9
print(list2) # [[1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 9]]
```

Comment: "should" as in you haven't tested it?

Comment: Yes, I could use "must" instead of "should". Some circumstances are (should be? :-) clear without testing

Comment: You're right, it was clear that this won't fix it, but I tested it anyway.

Comment: Your change doesn't have any effect other than preventing burning a few more CPU cycles.

Answer (score -1):

Backtracking is a general algorithm "that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons each partial candidate ("backtracks") as soon as it determines that the candidate cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution." (Wikipedia).

So, basically, what you do is build incrementally all permutations. As soon as as you build a single permutation, you backtrack and build another one, and so on until you generate all n! possible permutations, say, on n symbols.

Example: n=3, S={1,2,3}.

You start with 1. Then you move forward an choose 2 (since 1 has already been chosen), and then you choose 3. At that point you have built the first permutation 123. Then you backtrack and select 3 instead of 2, then select 2, and you have 132. You backtrack again, but you have already used 2 and 3, so you backtrack again (one level up where), and choose 2 instead of 1, then you select 1, and finally 3, so you have 213.